# Passive form of "Who knows what to do?"

Tags: passive-voice

> Who knows what to do?

How to make it in a passive form?

Actually, I am confused. I changed it like this.

> What to do is known to whom?

Is correct? What about these?

> What to do is known to by whom?
>   What to do is known by whom?

Please correct me.

Comment: What to be done is known by who(m)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two verbs in the sentence: *knows* and *do*.  You've tried to change *knows* into passive voice, and all of those sentences are very awkward.

On the other hand, making *do* passive works:

> Who knows what is to be done?

Answer (score 1):

A less awkward example could be:

> By whom is it known what to do?

or,

> To whom is it known what to do?

But still, if you really (that's a big IF) need to switch it to a passive voice, I believe [200_success's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67646/22747) is best.